# Dynamically add WHERE parameters to a PDO sql statement

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I need to build an SQL statement in PHP using PDO and the number of values in the WHERE clause are dynamic.

e.g.

```
SELECT column1, column2 FROM table WHERE category = :category OR category = :category
```

In this case there are 2 categories in the where clause I'm comparing, but it could be more than 2 so I can't just use :category1 and :category2 as the names.

I tried the following, but it's giving a "General error: 2031" message

```
  $where = array("category = :category", "category = :category");
  $params = array("abc", "xyz");
  $query = "SELECT column1, column2 FROM table WHERE ". implode(" OR ", $where);
  $s= $h->prepare($query);
  $s->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $s->execute(array_values($params));
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If there are many categories, use a SQL `IN` statement

You can look here for how to bind it to your array:
[Can I bind an array to an IN() condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/920353/can-i-bind-an-array-to-an-in-condition)

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies.  I'll look into the IN() condition.

Comment: This should have been posted as a duplicate flag, not as an answer.

Comment: @Shadow If OP doesn't know about the `IN` statement he can't search for how to bind parameters to it.

Comment: The fact that the OP could not have found the other topic through a search has nothing to do with its question being a duplicate. Marking a question as a duplicate of another one tells the OP that his/her question has already been answered here on SO.

Answer (score -1):

See above comment regarding IN statement, but in case if you still plan to use dynamically generated where part you should either use question mark (?) or create the unique name for each PDO pseudo variable:

```
$where = array("category = ?", "category = ?");
$params = array("abc", "xyz");
$query = "SELECT column1, column2 FROM table WHERE ". implode(" OR ", $where);
$s= $h->prepare($query);
$s->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$s->execute($params);
```

Read here for more details: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: you are partially right with your statement but you should pay more attention to the code you are posting